# .htaccess ensure www redirect incorrect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to ensure that urls always have www in front of them for canonicalization reasons.

Unfortunately when I put the following url in:

http://website.net/handbags/1/12/this-is-some-text

It redirects me here:

http://www.website.net/?controller=handbags&path=1/12/this-is-some-text

I would like to add it works fine when using:

http://www.website.net/handbags/1/12/this-is-some-text

I want it to redirect me here...

http://www.website.net/handbags/1/12/this-is-some-text

I'm not sure what could be causing this error. Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # CORE REDIRECT
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?(.*)?$ index.php?controller=$1&path=$2 [NC,L]

    # ENSURE WWW
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.               [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.[a-z]{2,6})$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$       http://www.%1/$1      [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the "# ENSURE WWW" code up, before the "# CORE REDIRECT" section?

Comment: @Martin Cernac - Yes I have tried re-arranging, it gives me "Fatal error: Class 'controller_index' not found" even when using the correct url. And if I remove the www it gives me the non-clean urls as well

Comment: Well, that's totally unrelated to .htaccess, as it's obviously a PHP error.

Comment: @Johannes H - It isn't php error. If I have it as in the example there are no php errors.

Comment: I was referring to the "Fatal error: Class 'controller_index' not found". APache cannot output such things - that has to be coming from a different source.

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    # ENSURE WWW
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.               [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.[a-z]{7})$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$       http://www.%1/$1      [R=301,L]

    # CORE REDIRECT
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?(.*)?$ index.php?controller=$1&path=$2 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

You can do what I've done above; however, it's just going to redirect to http://www.website.net/handbags/1/12/this-is-some-text and then it's immediately going to hit the "CORE REDIRECT" rule and send you to http://www.website.net/?controller=handbags&path=1/12/this-is-some-text.

Is there a reason you don't want it to redirect to "?controller=handbags" when they go to www?

**UPDATE**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    # ENSURE WWW
    Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.net
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$       http://www.website.net/$1      [R=301,L]

    # CORE REDIRECT
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?(.*)?$ index.php?controller=$1&path=$2 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yes, I am building an MVC framework and I want clean looking urls :)

Comment: Then you need to remove the CORE REDIRECT rule.

Comment: I need that rule because I need to split the url and send it into the $_GET array for use by the php controller

Comment: I see now what was happening. Did my modified code work for you?

Comment: no it just created a php error even when using the correct urls :)

Comment: That's because those "non-celan" urls are necesary for your PHP script to work. The PHP script seems to look for GET parameters, so you cannot just strip them away ^^

Comment: Sorry, I was commenting on the wrong answer. I've edited my answer again.

Comment: Yes but I should be able to get a clean looking url in the address bar through a re-write surely..

Comment: It is sending controller=index into the $_GET array now

Comment: That's what you wanted it to do, right? So that you could have clean URLs? Or are you saying it's becoming $_GET['controller=index'] instead of $_GET['controller'] equaling 'index'?

Comment: http:// www. website.net/handbags/1/12/this-is-some-text is where I would like to rewrite to and I would like $_GET array to have controller to be link and the path to be 1/12/this-is-some-text

Comment: What does this mean? "It is sending controller=index into the $_GET array now" Does that mean my answer fixed your problem or no?

Comment: Sorry Nick it doesn't seem to be working thumbs up for effort though

Comment: If you don't have more than one domain pointed to the server, I would change your WWW rewrite to my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your `# CORE REDIRECT` matches, the other rules are not even checked, as the core redirect rule has the `L`flag set. That ones tells Apache to stop trying other rules. Remove that flag or change the rule. ;)

Comment: Still gives me the non-clean looking urls in the redirect when I remove the www :)

Comment: What URLs DOES it give you, and what URLs do you LIKE to have? Little more context wouldn't be a bad thing right now ;)

Comment: Just added what I'd like the url to be rewritten to

Comment: I've edited my code slightly. Also, I noticed you're checking for a domain that's between two and six in length. How long is your domain name?

Comment: I am? It is 7 characters long in reality